# Flutter Flame: how to use parallax with camera.followComponent?

Tags: flutter, flame

Using Flutter Flame I'm trying to create a parallax background for a side scrolling game, where the camera focuses on the hero. I've only found examples of a constant speed scrolling parallax, but not one that respects the camera movement in the game world.

If I give a non zero `baseVelocity` to the parallax, it will keep scrolling even if the camera is not moving. If I set `baseVelocity` to zero, the parallax backgrounds will move as the camera moves, but the actual parallax effect is not visible (i.e. all layers just scroll uniformly as the camera moves).

Is there a setup where I can use `camera.followComponent` and the built-in `ParallaxComponent` so that the background layers will move with a parallax effect, when the camera follows the subject? Or do I have to implement my own parallax background that respects camera movements?

This is what I've tried:

Parallax background component:

```
class BackgroundComponent extends ParallaxComponent {
  double? lastCameraX;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    parallax = await gameRef.loadParallax(
      _imageNames,
      // baseVelocity: Vector2(0.0, 0.0),
      velocityMultiplierDelta: Vector2(1.8, 1.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
    );
  }

  static final _imageNames = [
    ParallaxImageData('background/parallax-mountain-bg.png'),
    ParallaxImageData('background/parallax-mountain-mountain-far.png'),
    ParallaxImageData('background/parallax-mountain-mountains.png'),
    ParallaxImageData('background/parallax-mountain-trees.png'),
    ParallaxImageData('background/parallax-mountain-foreground-trees.png'),
  ];

}
```

FlameGame onload:

```
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    Flame.device.setLandscape();
    add(BackgroundComponent()); // This is the parallax background

    final hero= Hero();
    add(hero);

    camera.speed = 1;
    camera.followComponent(hero, relativeOffset: const Anchor(0.2, 1));
  }
```

**UPDATE**
Based on spydon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71133060/405481) I ended up with the following parallax component, and it works now as intended. I.e. the parallax effect is tied to the camera movement.

```
class BackgroundComponent extends ParallaxComponent {
  Vector2 lastCameraPosition = Vector2.zero();

// here comes onLoad(), loading the actual images - not relevant
// ...

  @override
  Future<void> update(double dt) async {
    super.update(dt);
    final cameraPosition = gameRef.camera.position;
    final delta = dt > threshold ? 1.0 / (dt * framesPerSec) : 1.0;
    final baseVelocity = cameraPosition
      ..sub(lastCameraPosition)
      ..multiply(backgroundVelocity)
      ..multiply(Vector2(delta, delta));
    parallax!.baseVelocity.setFrom(baseVelocity);
    lastCameraPosition.setFrom(gameRef.camera.position);
  }

  static final backgroundVelocity = Vector2(3.0, 0);
  static const framesPerSec = 60.0;
  static const threshold = 0.005;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll have to set the `ParallaxComponent` to not move the component itself with the camera (this was a bug from our side, it will be default in the next version).

You do this by setting `positionType = PositionType.viewport;` in the component (or override that field).

Now you can connect the `camera.position` to the `baseVelocity` of your parallax, something like this for example:

```dart
class BackgroundComponent extends ParallaxComponent {
  Vector2 lastCameraPosition = Vector2.zero();

// here comes onLoad(), loading the actual images - not relevant
// ...

  @override
  Future<void> update(double dt) async {
    super.update(dt);
    final cameraPosition = gameRef.camera.position;
    final delta = dt > threshold ? 1.0 / (dt * framesPerSec) : 1.0;
    final baseVelocity = cameraPosition
      ..sub(lastCameraPosition)
      ..multiply(backgroundVelocity)
      ..multiply(Vector2(delta, delta));
    parallax!.baseVelocity.setFrom(baseVelocity);
    lastCameraPosition.setFrom(gameRef.camera.position);
  }

  static final backgroundVelocity = Vector2(3.0, 0);
  static const framesPerSec = 60.0;
  static const threshold = 0.005;
}
```

(The resulting code was written by András Szepesházi).

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying along the same lines but without success. I've also tried your exact solution copy-paste and did not have the desired effect. I'll prepare a minimal repo and post it here. Would greatly appreciate if you could have a look. Cheers

Comment: Interesting, what effect does it have? I didn't try it before I replied.

Comment: Your approach was on spot, I just had to fix a couple of small issues (no call to super.update(), and the velocity calculation was off a bit). I'll add the updated version to my answer. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, I updated my answer so that it is easier for people coming across this question to see the answer.
If you want to you could submit a PR with an example for this for the Flame examples site. :)

Comment: I'm using flame: ^1.13.1, any idea why there's no `camera.position` available?

Comment: @gotnull Flame has a more advanced camera system now, so it's `camera.viewfinder.position`.